# Testing Reusable Symfony Bundles with PHPUnit Bridge

Tags: symfony, phpunit, bundle

I recently ran across [PHPUnit Bridge](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-phpunit-bridge), and have been using it in any of my standalone Symfony apps. However, I noticed some deprecation notices coming through for a reusable bundle dependency that we maintain.

To diagnose, I opened up the reusable bundle project and installed `symfony/phpunit-bridge`, but after running `phpunit` noticed that there were no deprecation notices, etc, being output for the project.

So how do you utilize the `symfony/phpunit-bridge` package with reusable bundles?

Comment: *I tried installing the package for this bundle* Wasn't the package already installed? What package did you test with `phpunit`? Have you installed the PHPUnit Bridge for this package?

Comment: @A.L I updated the description to clarify a bit. I installed PHPUnit Bridge for a personal reusable bundle after seeing the deprecations notices bubbling up in a project that utilizes that personal bundle. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks, I see your problem now. Do tests from your app and your bundle use the same code? Do they use the same environment? It seems that the bundle tests don't call deprecated code and never trigger notices.

Comment: @A.L the deprecation notices are coming from the service configuration layer. Right now in that bundle its set up via YAML. But as a reusable bundle, its also not set up within the full framework where those files would be parsed, so I suspect you're right in that regard re: uncalled code.

Comment: I used [this method](http://www.whitewashing.de/2012/02/25/symfony2_controller_testing.html) to test one of my bundle, an [AppKernel](https://github.com/alexislefebvre/AsyncTweetsBundle/blob/master/Tests/App/AppKernel.php) is booted and I'm pretty sure that the YAML file `routing.yml` file is read.

Comment: It's not a bad approach...unfortunately, if I wanted to keep everything self-contained in the reusable bundle, I'd need to add a dev dependency on symfony/http-kernel. This in turn would throw off any other packages requiring that likely already have their own dependency on the kernel defined. But that approach would definitely work as a standalone project for testing reusable bundles.

Comment: @A.L Your comment did eventually get me to an answer. Ultimately, there needs to be a test class in the reusable bundle for testing our Extension class. This will ensure all the expected configuration has taken place, and, in this particular case, also trigger the expected deprecation notices.

If you'd like to make the note re: missed execution paths (from 11/20 @ 15:11) an answer, I'd be happy to add some additional context and award the bounty.

Comment: *I'd need to add a dev dependency on symfony/http-kernel*, I don't think it's a problem. My [composer.json requires `"symfony/symfony": "~2.3 || ~3.0"`](https://github.com/alexislefebvre/AsyncTweetsBundle/blob/f018706307b52ae9a21d96675007792a7f2b7d92/composer.json#L16) and you can see that [Travis CI installed Symfony 2.6, 2.7 or 2.8 without any problem](https://travis-ci.org/alexislefebvre/AsyncTweetsBundle/builds/90393048). Since this is a Bundle for Symfony2, the `"symfony/symfony"` package should already be installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I noticed some deprecation notices coming through for a reusable bundle dependency that we maintain.
>
> To diagnose, I opened up the reusable bundle project and installed `symfony/phpunit-bridge`, but after running `phpunit` noticed that there were no deprecation notices, etc, being output for the project.

The fact that the same code does not always trigger the same warnings may indicate that the tests are different.

If this comes from PHP code, you can see tested and untested code by using [PHP_CodeCoverage](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage). When you use PHPUnit, you can add an option in order to generate a code coverage report, e.g. `phpunit … --coverage-html cov/` will generate an HTML report in the `cov/` directory. By comparing the outputs, you can see if tests launched from Symfony call the same code that the tests launched from the Bundle.

If the tests are different, you can [set up a Symfony environment for your bundle](http://www.whitewashing.de/2012/02/25/symfony2_controller_testing.html):

> #### Create a TestKernel
>
> ```
> <?php
> // Tests/Controller/App/AppKernel.php
>
> use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
> use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;
>
> class AppKernel extends Kernel
> {
>     public function registerBundles()
>     {
>         $bundles = array(
>             // Dependencies
>             new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
>             [...]
>             // My Bundle to test
>             new Beberlei\WorkflowBundle\BeberleiWorkflowBundle(),
>         );
>
>         return $bundles;
>     }
>
>     public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
>     {
>         // We don't need that Environment stuff, just one config
>         $loader->load(__DIR__.'/config.yml');
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> #### Creating the config.yml
>
> ```
> # Tests/Controller/App/config.yml
> framework:
>     secret:          secret
>     charset:         UTF-8
>     test: ~
>     router:          { resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/routing.yml" }
>     form:            true
>     csrf_protection: true
>     validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
>     templating:      { engines: ['twig'] }
>     session:
>         auto_start:     false
>         storage_id: session.storage.filesystem
>
> monolog:
>     handlers:
>         main:
>             type:         fingers_crossed
>             action_level: error
>             handler:      nested
>         nested:
>             type:  stream
>             path:  %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log
>             level: debug
> ```
>
> #### Creating the routing.yml
>
> ```
> # Tests/Controller/App/routing.yml
> BeberleiWorkflowBundle:
>     resource: "@BeberleiWorkflowBundle/Controller/"
>     type:     annotation
>     prefix:   /
> ```
>
> #### Modifying the phpunit.xml.dist
>
> ```
> <!-- phpunit.xml.dist -->
> <phpunit bootstrap="Tests/bootstrap.php">
>     <php>
>         <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="Tests/Controller/App" />
>     </php>
> </phpunit>
> ```

Then, you can add `"symfony/symfony": "~2.3"` in the required packages in <kbd>composer.json</kbd> and install the packages. Future tests will boot this AppKernel and perform tests in a complete Symfony environment.